# Why does a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException happen here?

Tags: java, android, arrays, bounds

I got the following code in my Android-App:

```
Event[] events = retrieveEvents();
if (events != null && events.length>0) {
   int eventNr = getFromUserInput();
   eventNr = eventNr % events.length;
   Event event = events[eventNr];
}
```

retrieveEvents() gets some `Event`s from the Internet, so this can fail an though be empty or `null`. The user can select which `Event` to display, to avoid a Exception I use the modulo operation to ensure the `eventNr` is within bounds. This works fine on any devices I tested on BUT:

I get error-reports from other users where the second last line (the array-access) throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. How can this happen? What condition have I left unchecked? Where is my error?

Remember: The `retrieveEvents()` and the `getFromUserInput()` function can both return invalid data, but I think I checked every case, so where is my fault?

Comment: So you *do* get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? On which line? the `Event event = events[eventNr];` line?

Comment: @aioobe: Yes, he said *"where the second last line (the array-access) throws..."*

Comment: What's the index in the exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you ensured that `eventNr` is never negative? The check isn't in your quoted code. The problem being that if, for instance, `eventNr` is `-1` and `events.length` is 5, `-1 % 5 = -1` and of course `events[-1]` is out of bounds.

Comment: No, but even if it was, where would be the problem?

Comment: @theomega: If `eventNr` is, say, `-1` and `events.length` is `5`, `-1 % 5 = -1` and `events[-1]` is out of bounds.

Comment: an index (eventNr) of -x (-5%4 = -1)

Comment: Oh, I thought negative modulo is always positive, but it isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is this a threaded application?  Is it possible that retrieveEvents() is always returning a reference to the same array, but that the array is being modified in real time?  If so, that could be your issue.

Comment: Never thought of this, although the application is not threaded it could be a concurrency-problem, I have to investigate that.

Comment: Good point. All of the quoted code *looks* like local vars, but that could just be a quoting code thing. Good question to ask, at least.